# Need help to set up a VPN using ASUS RT-N12D1 router through AT&T UVerse Router

Tags: networking, router, vpn, home-networking

N12D1 router which can be configured to setup PPPT VPN  . How can i setup VPN through the AT&T Router . since when i connect it to the routers ethernet i get a private IP Address ? Thanks

Comment: You will have to setup NAT and firewall rules on the AT&T router.

Answer (score 0):

Set your ASUS router up with a static IP on your current subnet and setup PPTP port forwarding to that static IP on your uverse router.  You could also try to setup the second router as a DMZ as well.